# Can not make POST request when testing my form

Tags: python, django, tdd

I need to make a form test with django TestCase but when I make a self.client.post request there is 404 status code -

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

Form works good in browser. If I print response after post request I have all data printed but status code keeps 404 and data does not save to db. Where can be the problem?
Here is my test:

```
   def test_post(self):
        '''
         Check form saves data
        '''

        self.response = self.client.post(reverse('user_detail', kwargs={'pk': 1}), {'name': 'Pablo'})

        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code,200)
```

View:

```
class ContactUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Contact
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'edit.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('user_detail', kwargs={'pk': 1})
```

Form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    The model for Contact model edit
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'bio', 'other_contacts', 
            'email', 'jabber', 'skype', 'other_contacts', 'photo']
        widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

Url:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', ContactUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='user_detail'),
```

Comment: Are you creating the User with pk 1 anywhere?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Yes.I have only one user but  pk 1 should be used when there is  UpdateView.

Comment: But have you created it *in your test*?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman In other tests I create user with person = Contact() person.name = 'Pablo'. But in this case user should be created by client.post. Or I misunderstood something? All pk`s are only for urls not for user db entries.

Comment: First of all, changes made by a test to the test database are dropped immediately after said test is run. You'll need to use a fixture or `setUpTestData()` to create persistent test data. Also, `UpdateView` should be expected to modify an existing user, not create a new one. Finally, you should show your `urls.py`, but I'm guessing the one you are reaching for is using the pk field to lookup a user in your database.

Comment: @Adam Starrh I have a fixture. And when i update it within this test it still keep s data from the fixture and the same code 404 in response.status_code.

Comment: Well a 404 means you're url isn't resolving. So for some reason your fixture isn't successfully creating a Contact object with a pk of 1 for your test to modify.

Comment: @ Adam Starrh Ok. now status code is 200, but model still does not want to save data from client.post. In the same time when I print response new data  is there but model keeps old data from fixture.